# how to get haptics feedback when touching a specific location?

Tags: android, touch-event

I want to give the user a haptics feedback when he/she touches a specific location on screen, bounded by x and y coordinates like a rectangle, something like this:

```
if (x > 050
                        && x < 100
                        && y > 50
                        && y < 100) {
// do some code

//then enter haptics feedback
}
```

the only way I got is to add haptics to certain views like buttons, is it applicable on a general touch event??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilize the [vibrator system service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) at any given time. Small sample that could go into the `if` block of your question *(vibrates for 500ms)*:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) ctx.getSystemService(Service.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(500);
```

*`ctx` is a context instance here*

But don't forget to add the relevant permission into the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: not sure but doesnt `ctx` have to be the activity extending class to be able to access getSystem... ?

Comment: @NikkyD [`getSystemService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String)) is a `Context` method. So every class instance that is either a Context or a class extending Context works. E.g. you can call this directly like `Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Service.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);` when you write this code into a `Activity` or a `Service` without the context object at all, since both extend the Context class.

Comment: Exactly, I used it directly in my activity
     Vibration vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

Comment: Note that when using this approach to provide haptic feedback, if your user turns off vibrations settings on their phone, your app will continue to vibrate when you use the vibrator service; at least this is true on my galaxy nexus.